# How can I use stored verifier,token and secret to get authorization when the app is re-open?

Tags: android, twitter4j

I use twitter4j in my android application. I can get oauth_verifier and fetch token and secret ( with  accessToken.getToken() and accessToken.getTokenSecret() ). I store those value.

However,I don't know how to use this value when the app open again.I found something like this.

accessToken = this.twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);

but how can I create requestToken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you got the token and the token secret save them in your app , example using [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

```
AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(oathVerifier);
SharedPreferences pref= getSharedPreferences("social_pref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString("token",accessToken.getToken());
editor.putString("token_secret",accessToken.getTokenSecret());
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
editor.apply();
}else{
editor.commit();
}
```

Now you can easily know if there is a stored token and token secret

```
public boolean doIhaveTokenAndTokenSecret(Context context){
 SharedPreferences pref= getSharedPreferences("social_pref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
return pref.getString("token",null)!=null && pref.getString("token_secret",null)!=null ;

}
```

if you have them stored provide them to ConfigurationBuilder object

```
ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
if(doIhaveTokenAndTokenSecret(getApplicationContext()){
            SharedPreferences mSharePref = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SOCIAL_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                builder.setOAuthAccessToken(mSharePref.getString("token",null));
                builder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(mSharePref.getString("token_secret",null));

}
            Configuration configuration = builder.build();
            Twitter mTwitter = new TwitterFactory(configuration).getInstance();
```